# How should I set up NavController?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lIu7.png)
After I run it has been closed and cannot be displayed.
Activity com.example.navigationdemo.MainActivity@1755f0c does not have a NavController set on 2131230916

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        NavController controller=Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.fragmentContainerView);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this,controller);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController controller=Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.fragmentContainerView);
        return controller.navigateUp();
        //return super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your navigation_graph?

Comment: I edited it. Is it the photo above?

Comment: Nope remove the image and post the graph in xml ,i.e. on the top right select the code and paste whatever is there over here

Comment: I don't quite understand your explanation. My English is not good. Can you see the photos I provided? And are the photos what you need?